# MySQL consuming a lot of CPU

Tags: mysql, sysdba

I’m having trouble with a new server. I installed the optimized configuration for Ubuntu server with EasyEngine of VirtuBox.

When migrating my website with template newspaper, the CPU consumption is very high.

Here is a [mysql tuner report](https://pastebin.com/sTrBTDtY).

[image]

[image]

[image]

MySQL tuner result:

[image: MySQL tuner result]

I have a database with more than 400 thousand posts. My server is:

- Intel Core i7-6700K CPU
- HDD 250 GB SSD
- RAM 16 GB DDR4-2133 PC4-17000

with easyengine + rediscache + wordpress.

With little access the consumption of CPU is a load average: 7.56, 3.43, 4.81.

Thank you in advance for your attention.

Comment: I am sorry to say, but I think you reached the limits of the wordpress + mysql world. You may check the mysql-slow.log (probably it will be mentioned in the answers you get), and try to tune your DB with adding new indexes, but... wordpress *holds large data in mysql in JSON format*, which is not indexable. I really won't say too many bad from the php + wordpress + mysql world, but I think the world would be better if people would start with system having lesser such structural limitations.

Comment: Showing your mysql config would be good. From the tuner report -disable your query cache - high overhead, low benefit. Add `skip-name-resolve`. Large number of temporary tables on disk - you need to sort out the slow queries. [log-slow-verbosity=query_plan,explain](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/explain-in-the-slow-query-log/), `long_query_time=0.1`. Use [pt-query-digest](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-query-digest.html). Use [COMPUTED COLUMNS](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/virtual-computed-columns/) to create indexes on JSON components and search on those.

Comment: Additional information request, please. Post on pastebin.com or here.
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -x when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
   includes hda & sda (SSD) filesystem type clues. 
for server tuning analysis.

Comment: High CPU in MySQL means one thing:  Poorly performing queries.  Find the slow queries; show them to us for critique.

Answer (score 0):

Use persistent connections, cpu will drop dramatically. Then check slow queries.

Comment: Persistent connections aren't that great on MySQL. Not sure how you came to this answer.

Comment: By spending the last ten years of my career as webmaster.

Comment: @danblack Persistent connections aren't _always_ that great. But sometimes they are. Especially if the client software is built to use persistency. Most modern web-engines are able to use `mysqlnd` properly.

Answer (score 0):

Observation, `Mysqltuner.pl` report indicates you have 32GB RAM rather than 16GB as indicated in your question information.

Suggestions to consider for your `my.cnf` `[mysqld]` section   Rate Per Second=RPS

```
innodb_io_capacity=10000  # from 200 to use more of SSD IOPS capacity
max_connections=200  # from 400 until you use more than 102 max_used_connections in a day
thread_cache_size=100  # from ? to reduce threads_created V8 refman CAP at 100
key_buffer_size=64M  # from 134M since less than 20% used
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8  # from 12 to continue avoiding mutex contention
innodb_lru_scan_depth=128  # from 1024 to conserve CPU cycles every second
read_buffer_size=256K  # from ? for ~ default to minimize handler_read_next RPS
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K  # from ? for ~ default to minimize handler_read_rnd_next RPS
aria_pagecache_age_threshold=900  # from 300 to delay age out
aria_pagecache_buffer_size=512M  # from 128M to reduce aria_pagecache_reads RPS
```

Please POST text results of `ulimit -a` from OS so we know your limits.